# Hanging indent in expex preamble

Tags: indentation, linguistics, expex

`expex` has a great way of displaying long glossed lines with a hanging indent by defining `\glhangindent` globall via `lingset`.  I would like to achieve this also for preamble (`\glpreamble`) and free translation (`\glft`)?

I have tried setting `\lingset{everyglpreamble=\hangindent=1em,everyglft=\hangindent=1em}` but this gives an error (outcommented below).

Alternatively I tried placing `\hangindent=1em` directly before each line, which works for `\glft` but not for `\glpreamble` (setting it for `glpreamble` results not in hanging indent but the entire line is indented).
Any way how to make this work and set it globally?  Help much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
%\lingset{everyglpreamble=\hangindent=1em,everyglft=\hangindent=1em}
\begin{document}
\ex \begingl
\glpreamble \hangindent=1em This is a very long sentence to be glossed and I would like the preamble also to have a hanging indent.//
\gla Gloss this//
\glb gl gl//
\glft \hangindent=1em This is a translation of a very long sentence to be glossed and I would like the free translation also to have a hanging indent.//
\endgl \xe
\end{document}
```

Just for clarification by hanging indent I mean:

```
This is a very long sentence to be glossed and I would 
        like it to have a hanging indent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brace the values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everyglpreamble={\hangindent=1em \hspace*{-\hangindent}},everyglft={\hangindent=1em }}
\begin{document}
\ex \begingl
\glpreamble This is a very long sentence to be glossed and I would like
            the preamble also to have a hanging indent.//
\gla Gloss this//
\glb gl gl//
\glft This is a translation of a very long sentence to be glossed and
      I would like the free translation also to have a hanging indent.//
\endgl \xe
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back, bracing does make hangindent work but unfortunately still not the way I want.  I still get first line indent and not hanging indent (also in the picture you attached).

Comment: @jan Maybe now it's what you'd like it to be?

Comment: Awesome!  (The best solutions are the simplest ...)